# How can a developer make an online ranking system for his game?

Tags: android, network-programming, ranking

I've been working on my game [MilkyWay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hasankamal.milkyway) which is free for android platform.

I wanted to know how can I make a worldwide ranking system for my users.
The game is simple and the users will simply be ranked upon their score. 
The user should just be showed his rank and nothing else, so it seems pretty simple to me.

But unfortunately, neither do I know much of the networking stuff nor do I have any clue of how to do this.

An elaborate answer will help me a lot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Currently OpenFeint for Android supports Leaderboards, Achievements,
>   Friending, and our Cross-Promotional tools. Our goal is to ensure
>   feature parity between Android and iOS versions in OpenFeint 3.0.
>
> Please note that the OpenFeint service will be discontinued on
>   December 14, 2012.
>
> Please see the OpenFeint Service Shutdown Announcement for more
>   information.

And new service name is GREE ...

https://docs.developer.gree.net/en/platform/

Comment: "Please note that the OpenFeint service will be discontinued on December 14, 2012." http://support.openfeint.com/dev/welcome/

Comment: Yes when user open the URL, will see the announcement ! THE NEW SERVICE WILL BE GREE ...  https://developer.gree.net/en/. Should i say everyting ? asker can see when he look at the site.